# PHP Script - Create table and then Import CSV to MySQL - Not Working

Tags: php, mysql

this script helps me to import a CSV file to MYSQL.. it will create a tabe with the file name and then import. but it is not working...

i don't know what is wrong in this script.. but it is showing me `Errors: file cannot be opened: [empty]` it is showing me the same error again and again

**INDEX**

```
<?php
include "Quick_CSV_import.php";

//connect to database
mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
mysql_select_db("database_name"); //your database

$csv = new Quick_CSV_import();

$arr_encodings = $csv->get_encodings(); //take possible encodings list
$arr_encodings["default"] = "[default database encoding]"; //set a default (when the default database encoding should be used)

if(!isset($_POST["encoding"]))
  $_POST["encoding"] = "default"; //set default encoding for the first page show (no POST vars)

if(isset($_POST["Go"]) && ""!=$_POST["Go"]) //form was submitted
{
  $csv->file_name = $HTTP_POST_FILES['file_source']['tmp_name'];

  //optional parameters
  $csv->use_csv_header = isset($_POST["use_csv_header"]);
  $csv->field_separate_char = $_POST["field_separate_char"][0];
  $csv->field_enclose_char = $_POST["field_enclose_char"][0];
  $csv->field_escape_char = $_POST["field_escape_char"][0];
  $csv->encoding = $_POST["encoding"];

  //start import now
  $csv->import();
}
else
  $_POST["use_csv_header"] = 1;
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>
    <title>Quick CSV import</title>
 </head>

<body bgcolor="#f2f2f2">
  <h2 align="center">Quick CSV import</h2>
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table border="0" align="center">
      <tr>
        <td>Source CSV file to import:</td>
        <td rowspan="30" width="10px">&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="file" name="file_source" id="file_source" class="edt" value="<?=$file_source?>"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Use CSV header:</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="use_csv_header" id="use_csv_header" <?=(isset($_POST["use_csv_header"])?"checked":"")?>/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Separate char:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="field_separate_char" id="field_separate_char" class="edt_30"  maxlength="1" value="<?=(""!=$_POST["field_separate_char"] ? htmlspecialchars($_POST["field_separate_char"]) : ",")?>"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Enclose char:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="field_enclose_char" id="field_enclose_char" class="edt_30"  maxlength="1" value="<?=(""!=$_POST["field_enclose_char"] ? htmlspecialchars($_POST["field_enclose_char"]) : htmlspecialchars("\""))?>"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Escape char:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="field_escape_char" id="field_escape_char" class="edt_30"  maxlength="1" value="<?=(""!=$_POST["field_escape_char"] ? htmlspecialchars($_POST["field_escape_char"]) : "\\")?>"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Encoding:</td>
        <td>
          <select name="encoding" id="encoding" class="edt">
          <?
            if(!empty($arr_encodings))
              foreach($arr_encodings as $charset=>$description):
          ?>
            <option value="<?=$charset?>"<?=($charset == $_POST["encoding"] ? "selected=\"selected\"" : "")?>><?=$description?></option>
          <? endforeach;?>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3" align="center"><input type="Submit" name="Go" value="Import it" onclick=" var s = document.getElementById('file_source'); if(null != s && '' == s.value) {alert('Define file name'); s.focus(); return false;}"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
<?=(!empty($csv->error) ? "<hr/>Errors: ".$csv->error : "")?>
</body>
</html>
```

**Quick_CSV_import.php**

```
<?php
    class Quick_CSV_import
    {
      var $table_name; //where to import to
      var $file_name;  //where to import from
      var $use_csv_header; //use first line of file OR generated columns names
      var $field_separate_char; //character to separate fields
      var $field_enclose_char; //character to enclose fields, which contain separator char into content
      var $field_escape_char;  //char to escape special symbols
      var $error; //error message
      var $arr_csv_columns; //array of columns
      var $table_exists; //flag: does table for import exist
      var $encoding; //encoding table, used to parse the incoming file. Added in 1.5 version

      function Quick_CSV_import($file_name="")
      {
        $this->file_name = $file_name;
        $this->arr_csv_columns = array();
        $this->use_csv_header = true;
        $this->field_separate_char = ",";
        $this->field_enclose_char  = "\"";
        $this->field_escape_char   = "\\";
        $this->table_exists = false;
      }

      function import()
      {
        if($this->table_name=="")
          $this->table_name = "temp_".date("d_m_Y_H_i_s");

        $this->table_exists = false;
        $this->create_import_table();

        if(empty($this->arr_csv_columns))
          $this->get_csv_header_fields();

        /* change start. Added in 1.5 version */
        if("" != $this->encoding && "default" != $this->encoding)
          $this->set_encoding();
        /* change end */

        if($this->table_exists)
        {
          $sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE '".@mysql_escape_string($this->file_name).
                 "' INTO TABLE `".$this->table_name.
                 "` FIELDS TERMINATED BY '".@mysql_escape_string($this->field_separate_char).
                 "' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '".@mysql_escape_string($this->field_enclose_char).
                 "' ESCAPED BY '".@mysql_escape_string($this->field_escape_char).
                 "' ".
                 ($this->use_csv_header ? " IGNORE 1 LINES " : "")
                 ."(`".implode("`,`", $this->arr_csv_columns)."`)";
          $res = @mysql_query($sql);
          $this->error = mysql_error();
        }
      }

      //returns array of CSV file columns
      function get_csv_header_fields()
      {
        $this->arr_csv_columns = array();
        $fpointer = fopen($this->file_name, "r");
        if ($fpointer)
        {
          $arr = fgetcsv($fpointer, 10*1024, $this->field_separate_char);
          if(is_array($arr) && !empty($arr))
          {
            if($this->use_csv_header)
            {
              foreach($arr as $val)
                if(trim($val)!="")
                  $this->arr_csv_columns[] = $val;
            }
            else
            {
              $i = 1;
              foreach($arr as $val)
                if(trim($val)!="")
                  $this->arr_csv_columns[] = "column".$i++;
            }
          }
          unset($arr);
          fclose($fpointer);
        }
        else
          $this->error = "file cannot be opened: ".(""==$this->file_name ? "[empty]" : @mysql_escape_string($this->file_name));
        return $this->arr_csv_columns;
      }

      function create_import_table()
      {
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ".$this->table_name." (";

        if(empty($this->arr_csv_columns))
          $this->get_csv_header_fields();

        if(!empty($this->arr_csv_columns))
        {
          $arr = array();
          for($i=0; $i<sizeof($this->arr_csv_columns); $i++)
              $arr[] = "`".$this->arr_csv_columns[$i]."` TEXT";
          $sql .= implode(",", $arr);
          $sql .= ")";
          $res = @mysql_query($sql);
          $this->error = mysql_error();
          $this->table_exists = ""==mysql_error();
        }
      }

      /* change start. Added in 1.5 version */
      //returns recordset with all encoding tables names, supported by your database
      function get_encodings()
      {
        $rez = array();
        $sql = "SHOW CHARACTER SET";
        $res = @mysql_query($sql);
        if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0)
        {
          while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($res))
          {
            $rez[$row["Charset"]] = ("" != $row["Description"] ? $row["Description"] : $row["Charset"]); //some MySQL databases return empty Description field
          }
        }
        return $rez;
      }

      //defines the encoding of the server to parse to file
      function set_encoding($encoding="")
      {
        if("" == $encoding)
          $encoding = $this->encoding;
        $sql = "SET SESSION character_set_database = " . $encoding; //'character_set_database' MySQL server variable is [also] to parse file with rigth encoding
        $res = @mysql_query($sql);
        return mysql_error();
      }
      /* change end */

    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means that the file you are trying to read can not be opened for reading.

Reasons: May be the files is using by any other program OR may be you have opened it already. So close the csv file if you have opened it and then run the script.

Here is simple code for reading csv file and inserting it in to mysql

```
function readCSV($srcName){

 $row_index = 0;

 $fp = fopen($srcName,'r') or die("can't open file for reading");


 while($csv_line = fgetcsv($fp,5024))
{

    $row_index++;
    if($row_index == 1)
    {
        continue;
    }


    $url=mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($csv_line[0]));

    $str="insert into tableName(url) values('$url')";
    mysql_query($str);  


}

}

readCSV('your file path and name here');
```

Comment: no bro! it isn;t the problem... i tried copying it as duplicate and them importing it... but it didn't work... again same error...

Comment: Are you sure there is no file open wth the filename you are using inside your code for importing csv?

Comment: i closed every thing except my browser.. and the file isn't running in any way :( i'm using an example csv file, which i got along with this script. it is also not working. so i thought some thing wrong in the script...

Comment: bro did u have any similar script ?

Comment: Yes i have. I will try to get you shortly. Right now lunch time

Comment: check my answer, i have added simple code for reading csv and inserting into mysql table.

Answer (score 0):

Try using $_FILES instead of $HTTP_POST_FILES